# Problem with partition function when calculating equlibrium constant?

Tags: physical-chemistry, statistical-mechanics

For example a reaction is given as ($\pu{T = 1000 K}$),

$$\ce{2Na(g) <--> Na2 (g)}$$

The equilibrium constant,

$$\ce{K_{c} = \frac{\frac{q_{Na_{2}}}{V}}{(\frac{q_{Na}}{V})^2}}$$

But when considering the partition function for $\ce{Na2(g)}$. Teacher multiplied by another term which I don't understand.

The partition function for $\ce{2Na(g)}$,

$$\ce{q_{Na} = q^{t}.q^{e}}$$

The partition function for $\ce{Na2(g)}$,

$$\ce{q_{Na_{2}} = q^{t}.q^{r}.q^{v}.q^{e}.e^{β(D_{o} - \frac{hν}{2})}}$$

1. Where dose this $\ce{e^{β(D_{o} - \frac{hν}{2})}}$ term come from why it has been used in the partition function from my understanding its coming from [Morse Oscillator](https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Pacific_Union_College/Quantum_Chemistry/05%3A_The_Harmonic_Oscillator_and_the_Rigid_Rotor/5.03%3A_The_Harmonic_Oscillator_Approximates_Vibrations). Looks like it has some thing to do with bond dissociation for a diatomic molecule but I don't understand how did it get resemble to the partition function.
2. Teacher took $\ce{q^{e}}$ for $\ce{Na(g)}$ as $\pu{2}$ and for $\ce{Na_{2}(g)}$  $\pu{1}$ how did that work according to my understanding,

The electronic partition function is given as,

$$\pu{q^{e} = g_{o}e^{-βE_{o}} + g_{1}e^{-βE_{1}} + g_{2}e^{-βE_{2}} ....}$$

Teacher only considered the ground state energies how did the other terms got neglected if ground state energy is $\pu{0}$ then only degeneracy matter.Further more I did not find any doubts about the other partition functions they are ok for me.

Comment: The Morse potential term arises from the nuclear degree of freedom term, thus for your diatomic $q = q_{\rm trans}q_{\mathrm rot}q_{\mathrm vib}q_{\mathrm elec}q_{\mathrm nucl}$. Your expression for $q_{\mathrm elec}$ is missing the first term - $\omega_{e1}$ - which is what the term converges to in a common approximation. The factor of 2 is simply because there are 2 $\ce{Na}$. Finally, your teacher copied this example (exactly) from p. 144 (section 9-2 A) in McQuarrie ${\it Statistical\, Mechanics}$ (1976), so you can look there to clear up the rest of your concerns.